# ld: file too small for architecture i386

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, opencv

So I am trying to create a simple `OpenCV` project. I downloaded `OpenCV` from here:

http://opencv.org/downloads.html

I have unarchived the downloaded file with:

```
tar xzvf opencv2.framework
```

I downloaded and installed latest `XCode 4.6` for `Mountain Lion` + command line tools. I then created a new app called `GeekOut` in `XCode` and linked `OpenCV` framework to it:

[image]

This is what I get when I click run:

[image]

Any ideas? I have been struggling with this for several hours. I have created like 6 new projects and tried linking the library in different ways (drag and drop, by clicking on + in Link Binary With Libraries under Build Phases tab etc).

Comment: I would love to see what happens when you build your program directly from the command line:  **g++ test.cpp -o test \`pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv\`**

Comment: @karlphillip I don't have any cpp files, it's objective C. I am following this tutorial: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/ios/hello/hello.html#opencvioshelloworld

Comment: Drag and dropping the framework seems to work for me. Have you tried re-downloading the framework? Switching to device (not simulator) scheme?

Comment: @zrxq When I test it on device, I get error as well. It says 
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CvVideoCamera", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Why do you reference CvVideoCamera from ViewController, it's not in the tutorial! I guess your problem is you're linking C++ library against Obj-C (as opposed to Obj-C++), but I'm not sure.

Comment: see that:[stackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27772151/apple-mach-o-linker-warning-directory-not-found-for-option/37894243#37894243) it will solve that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xcode linker error: file too small for architecture x86\_64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034048/xcode-linker-error-file-too-small-for-architecture-x86-64)

Answer (score 9):

Have you tried to clean build (Cmd+K)?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved it just by copying the "opencv2" file from .../opencv2.framework/Versions/A/ into .../opencv2.framework/

Answer (score 0):

Problem  is on your architecture.So 
change the architecture to armv7

Answer (score 0):

Try a simple "Clean" and "Build" : Cmd + Shift + K