# Apple Mach-O Linker Warning "Directory Not Found For Option..."

Tags: ios, objective-c, linker-errors, linker-warning

I simply want to rid of the warnings that pop up like these:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/m/Desktop/FacebookSDK'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/m/Desktop/FacebookSDK/FBAudienceNetwork'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/gavin/Downloads/shaffiulla11-bat-b86d81d8adc6'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/gavin/Desktop/shaffiulla11-bat-b86d81d8adc6'
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/Gavin/Desktop/FacebookSDK/Bolts.framework/Bolts, missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Users/Gavin/Desktop/FacebookSDK/Bolts.framework/Bolts (2 slices)
```

Obviously I am using different directories now because of multiple reformats of my drive because of Logic Board issues and just would like to know the most convenient way I can get rid of these errors. Thanks for the time and help.

Answer (score 149):

Go into your Projects settings and remove the excess Frameworks paths in there that you don't need.

Here's what it looks like when I open my project's build settings:

[image: Open Build Settings]

Click on "Framework Search Paths" and you should find the bogus paths listed in there, which you can delete.

Comment: Yeah check the project settings and target settings. The target settings override the project settings.

Comment: I could only fix my issue after removing the existing values from the Library Search Path leaving only $(inherited) there.

Answer (score 6):

I sat on this issue for like more than a week before figuring out. For me the issue was a missing pod reference. And the error it was showing in xcode was weird. When I say weird they don't tell you what exactly is missing or the error.
See the image below:￼
And the issue was around the test target. I was exhausted trying out all the Framework search paths and Library Search Paths reset or removing them from the project as well. Nothing worked.

**And finally I did a guess and added the Google analytics pod to both test target and main app target and bang..it started working. Crazy!!!**
The error here in the image if you see denotes something to do with architecture. I even played around with the architecture settings.

So it's all about a pod missing in the target that you are trying to compile.
Hope this helps.

[image: GGL analytics pod was not found]

Comment: Hey. how did you exactly add the pod in both targets?