# Why do I get this warning when building an iOS application (Swift)?

Tags: ios

This is the warning:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.0.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks'
```

How can I fix the problem (if any)?

Comment: Does the app work in the Simulator? Does everything work as intended?

Comment: yes, app is working but why do i get this warning.

Comment: the error means **'-F/Applications** some framework path is missing , check once for reference see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27772151/apple-mach-o-linker-warning-directory-not-found-for-option

Answer (score 1):

This is a common error when converting a older project to Swift 2.x in Xcode 7 (though you might see it in other conversions, too). Specifically, I frequently see this error in the tests target when opening old projects:

[image]

This is often a result of incorrect value in the "Framework Search Paths" of the tests target:

[image]

If you remove the string in that "Framework Search Paths" for the appropriate target, that error will go away. For some reason, Xcode doesn't generally introduce this error in the main target, but only the tests target.

--

As an aside, when opening up an old project, it's good practice to select the target and then choosing "Validate Settings..." from the "Editor" menu. A lot of cryptic error messages will be resolved when you do that.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Project Target->build Phase Check is there any red mark in file.[image]

Check The copy Bundle Resource ,compile Source everything ,if you are upgraded to xcode 7 ,then check the path if there is no red mark .

if you are using any third party library please give the path for that.

[image]

That search path is available in build setting in project target..

Hope this will helps you :)

Comment: if my answer is correct please choose it as right @Arun ,may be it will help to others who struggle with the same issues .....