# Xcode 7 warning - directory not found for option

Tags: ios, xcode, warnings

this answer didn't solved:

[‘ld: warning: directory not found for option’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9458739/ld-warning-directory-not-found-for-option)

after switching from old Xcode to new one an iOS 8 app, on my new mac I got

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.1.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks'

I tried creating the missing folder, but I still have a problem of strange incomplete autocomplete as frameworks were not there

[image]

Comment: Perform a build/clean and a "Clean build folder". That sometimes help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apple Mach-O Linker Warning "Directory Not Found For Option..."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27772151/apple-mach-o-linker-warning-directory-not-found-for-option)