# duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64 xcode linking error swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6.4

"Xcode 6.4 linking error while build project".i am using google analytics framework. Someone suggests the solution of this problem

Comment: There must be some duplicate constants. Can you post full error log ?

Comment: posting code/errors helps a lot

Answer (score -1):

I have posted my solution in this link. It has got nothing to do with architecture or whatever the crap xcode displays in the error logs.

In the podfile, if you are specifying test target and main target separately and using different sets of pods, then add Google analytics pod reference in both.
Like this:
pod 'Google/Analytics'

[Apple Mach-O Linker Warning "Directory Not Found For Option..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27772151/apple-mach-o-linker-warning-directory-not-found-for-option/37894243#37894243)

Please let me know if you had any luck with that. It worked for me.