# Handle "file too small" error message in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, libc++

I got this error:

> ld: file too small (length=19) file '/Users/xxx/xxx/xxx/libc++.dylib' for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

I have tried `clean/build` or `delete/re-add` with not luck.

Similar posts:

- [Xcode linker error: file too small for architecture x86_64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034048/xcode-linker-error-file-too-small-for-architecture-x86-64)
- [ld: file too small for architecture i386](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15849991/ld-file-too-small-for-architecture-i386)

Comment: have you deleted your derived-data ??

Comment: @dahiya_boy no , is this command rm -rf /Users/hostname/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData? what is the hostname?

Comment: you can check from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38016143/how-to-delete-derived-data-in-xcode-8?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa). Even close your xcode(force quit) and restart it now clen N build..

Comment: unfortunately it turns out that delete derived-data doe not work in my case...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xcode linker error: file too small for architecture x86\_64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034048/xcode-linker-error-file-too-small-for-architecture-x86-64)

Answer (score 2):

I solved this on Xcode 12.5.1 by going to "Clean Build Folder" under the Product menu on the top bar.