# Swift stdlib tool error when building to iPhone X - Xcode 9.1

Tags: swift4, xcode9.1

When I am trying to build to my iPhone, I am getting a "Swift stdlib tool Error, Task failed with exit 1 signal 0" When I double click on it, it takes me to the following in the Activity Log:

```
/Users/tommy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iBMR_2018-ershwxhoxphvmjgubqdoefmqqoyy/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/iBMR 2018.app/Frameworks/libswiftAVFoundation.dylib: code object is not signed at all
Codesigning /Users/tommy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iBMR_2018-ershwxhoxphvmjgubqdoefmqqoyy/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/iBMR 2018.app/Frameworks/libswiftAVFoundation.dylib
/usr/bin/codesign '--force' '--sign' '9CAA1DDB653D3C2804161CCBEFFD314ADA9DCD76' '--verbose' '/Users/tommy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iBMR_2018-ershwxhoxphvmjgubqdoefmqqoyy/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/iBMR 2018.app/Frameworks/libswiftAVFoundation.dylib'
/Users/tommy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iBMR_2018-ershwxhoxphvmjgubqdoefmqqoyy/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/iBMR 2018.app/Frameworks/libswiftAVFoundation.dylib: unknown error -1=ffffffffffffffff
error: Task failed with exit 1 signal 0 {
/usr/bin/codesign '--force' '--sign' '9CAA1DDB653D3C2804161CCBEFFD314ADA9DCD76' '--verbose' '/Users/tommy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iBMR_2018-ershwxhoxphvmjgubqdoefmqqoyy/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/iBMR 2018.app/Frameworks/libswiftAVFoundation.dylib'
}
```

When I searched on here, I found this question: [Swift stdlib tool Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40567666/swift-stdlib-tool-error)

I downloaded my profiles, and for iOS Development Certificates I have "Tommy's iMac" and "Untitled", both dated 11/8/17. The Untitled one has a red X and says "Missing Private Key", but the only option in there is to add another certificate, so not sure if that is why I'm having a problem or not;  nor what to do about that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue.  For some reason, recreation development  certificate and provision profile from the scratch resolved the issue. Thanks.

Comment: This ended up working for me. My apologies for not marking this as the answer before; it completely slipped my mind.