# AVFoundation errors when trying to run app on Xcode9 and Swift 3.2

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, error-handling, foundation

I have the following problem - I am getting a bunch of errors when I try to run my app using Xcode 9 and Swift 3.2. I have no idea what's wrong and will be very grateful if somebody gives me a hint about it. Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Try to clean your project (^⌘C).

Comment: @the4kman not working.

Comment: Deleting Derived Data might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38016143/how-to-delete-derived-data-in-xcode-8 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38227783/how-to-delete-derived-data-in-xcode8

Comment: Not working too. @AhmadF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I finally found what's wrong. The problem is that some of the AVFoundation APIs are temporarily not working.

```
AVCaptureDevice.Format.supportedColorSpaces
AVCaptureDevice.supportedFlashModes
AVCapturePhotoOutput.availablePhotoPixelFormatTypes
AVCapturePhotoOutput.availableRawPhotoPixelFormatTypes
AVCapturePhotoSettings.availablePreviewPhotoPixelFormatTypes
```

As a workaround, use the SwiftPrivate versions of these API by prepending each API with double underscore (`__`). For example, change `AVCaptureDevice.Format.supportedColorSpaces` to `AVCaptureDevice.Format.__supportedColorSpaces`.