# error: library not found for -lPods

Tags: ios, xcode, afnetworking, afnetworking-3

I downloaded this project with AFNetworking and lumberjack, and it won't compile.
The following is the error I received, can you guide me as to how to interpret it and if you know the error what is it ?

Ld /Users/nader/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SmartConfigCC31XX-axrpiaydjwsrwxhbpqketglbghrz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SimpleLink\ provisioning.app/SimpleLink\ provisioning normal x86_64
    cd /Users/nader/Documents/iOS/source
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=7.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator11.0.sdk -L/Users/nader/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SmartConfigCC31XX-axrpiaydjwsrwxhbpqketglbghrz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Users/nader/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SmartConfigCC31XX-axrpiaydjwsrwxhbpqketglbghrz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AFNetworking -L/Users/nader/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SmartConfigCC31XX-axrpiaydjwsrwxhbpqketglbghrz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/CocoaLumberjack -L/Users/nader/Documents/iOS/source/SmartConfigCC31XX -L/Users/nader/Documents/iOS/source/build/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/nader/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SmartConfigCC31XX-axrpiaydjwsrwxhbpqketglbghrz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/nader/Documents/iOS/source -filelist /Users/nader/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SmartConfigCC31XX-axrpiaydjwsrwxhbpqketglbghrz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/SmartConfigCC31XX.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SmartConfigCC31XX.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SimpleLink\ provisioning.LinkFileList -mios-simulator-version-min=7.0 -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/nader/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SmartConfigCC31XX-axrpiaydjwsrwxhbpqketglbghrz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/SmartConfigCC31XX.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SmartConfigCC31XX.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SimpleLink\ provisioning_lto.o -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -ObjC -lAFNetworking -lCocoaLumberjack -framework CoreGraphics -framework MobileCoreServices -framework Security -framework SystemConfiguration -ObjC -lAFNetworking -lCocoaLumberjack -framework CoreGraphics -framework MobileCoreServices -framework Security -framework SystemConfiguration -Xlinker -sectcreate -Xlinker __TEXT -Xlinker __entitlements -Xlinker /Users/nader/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SmartConfigCC31XX-axrpiaydjwsrwxhbpqketglbghrz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/SmartConfigCC31XX.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SmartConfigCC31XX.build/SimpleLink\ provisioning.app.xcent -lFirstTimeConfig -lCocoaLumberjack -framework SystemConfiguration -framework Security -framework AVFoundation -liconv -framework QuartzCore -framework CoreVideo -framework CoreMedia -framework CoreGraphics -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -lPods -lPods-SmartConfigCC31XX -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/nader/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SmartConfigCC31XX-axrpiaydjwsrwxhbpqketglbghrz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/SmartConfigCC31XX.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SmartConfigCC31XX.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SimpleLink\ provisioning_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/nader/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SmartConfigCC31XX-axrpiaydjwsrwxhbpqketglbghrz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SimpleLink\ provisioning.app/SimpleLink\ provisioning

ld: library not found for -lPods
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Do you have `.xcodeproj` file open or you opened `.xcworkspace` file?

Comment: i am using hte xcworkspace

Answer (score 0):

1. pod install
2. open your project from .xcworkspace
3. rebuild

Comment: I have already tried to open up with xcworkspace, it didnt work

Comment: did you try to clean your project and derived data?

Comment: yes, I did. I did a clean, and then followed these instructions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38227783/how-to-delete-derived-data-in-xcode8

Comment: could you share your pod file and a screenshot of your **Link with Binary** section inside your *Target* Build settings?

Answer (score 0):

Go to :
Yourproject -> Manage schemes -> tick on Pods-YourProject

It will add the pods project to your project.