# Error linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, linker

I have a problem with this error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
And I don't find the source of this error and give me the solution...
Thank for help

```
ld: file too small (length=0) file '/Users/idigao/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IDIPhone-exyhshsbrfefnsdkwluvaiimrcky/Build/Intermediates/IDIPhone.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/IDIPhone.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ContactTableViewController.o' for architecture x86_64
```

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034048/xcode-linker-error-file-too-small-for-architecture-x86-64

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open Xcode with .xcworkspace to resolve linker command failed issue

Comment: Thank's i have find the solution ! you just need to delete the DerivedData and open again my Xcode project