# How to solve "Linker command failed"

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

My Problem : "clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/si2gU.png)

What I've tried:

1. Updating Xcode and Mac os Sierra
2. Enable bitcode > YES
3. Quit and Restart System
4. I've checked all my files, and make sure that none of them have the same name.
5. All my pods are up to date.

Have the whole day try to fix this error :(

> ld: file too small (length=0) file '/Users/bukacakrawala/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Madeeng-dmphimsijmhlofbcyzagijdvnjor/Build/Intermediates/Madeeng.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Madeeng.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/InitialViewController.o' for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: You'll need to post a more full log. This error message can mean many things.

Comment: @meyer9 there, I just added my error log

Comment: Have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034048/xcode-linker-error-file-too-small-for-architecture-x86-64

Comment: Thanks. that solve ;) still no idea wha's happening tho!