# Error when building Projucer for JUCE framework on an older Mac

Tags: c++, cmake, juce

I'm currently experiencing an issue while trying to build the Projucer on an older Mac running macOS 10.15.7 (Catalina). I do not have Xcode installed, so I'm attempting to build Projucer using CMake and the command-line tools.

I have ensured that I'm using the latest version of `xcode-select` and I've tried building Projucer inside a `build` folder at the root of my JUCE folder with the `master` and `develop` branches, but I keep getting the same error message:

```
ld: file too small (length=0) file 
 'CMakeFiles/juceaide.dir/__/__/__/modules/juce_gui_basics/juce_gui_basics.mm.o'
 for architecture x86_64

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

make[2]: *** [extras/Build/juceaide/juceaide_artefacts/Debug/juceaide] Error 1

make[1]: *** [extras/Build/juceaide/CMakeFiles/juceaide.dir/all] Error 2

make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Does someone already faced this issue? I would greatly appreciate any suggestions or workarounds to help me build Projucer and start my project.

Comment: The file `juce_gui_basics.mm.o` could be empty because of crash on a previous build attempt. Have you tried to perform clean rebuild (or even clean reconfiguration, by removing build directory and running `cmake` again)? This is suggested in [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034048/xcode-linker-error-file-too-small-for-architecture-x86-64).

Comment: If by clean rebuild you strictly mean `rm -rf build` and then `cmake .. -DJUCE_BUILD_EXTRAS=ON` inside a newly created `build` folder, then yes I did that 3 times already

Comment: This is not a fix to the issue _per se_, but I was able to start using JUCE by downloading an old version of XCode and building Projucer with it.
However, I'm still curious to know why it was not working with CMake.